# problem with deriving continuity equation

Tags: derivatives, continuity, fluid-dynamics

I am studying Aerodynamics, to be more precise, the fundamentals of Aerodynamics. The first law is the continuity equation, for which it is explained in the book that I am using. However, I wished to derive this on my own... with the consequence that I cant. Therefore I hope that somebody might spot the mistake I did or corrects me in my attempt.

Basically, the continuity equation states:

\begin{equation}
m`_{out} - m`_{in} =\frac{dm}{dt}
\end{equation}

Now what I did is I assumed an imaginary small cube with lengths of a. Three of those surfaces will be the entry of the flow, the other three the outlet of the flow.

Therefore we can write the equation as:
\begin{equation}
((\rho+d\rho)(v+dv)(3a^2))-(\rho v (3a^2)) = \frac{\delta}{\delta t} (p dV)
\end{equation}

Rewriting this, we get to:
\begin{equation}
(3a^2)((\rho+d\rho)(v+dv) - (\rho v)) = \frac{\delta}{\delta t} (p dV)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
(3a^2)(\rho v + \rho dv + vd\rho + d\rho dv - \rho v) = \frac{\delta}{\delta t} (p dV)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
(3a^2)(\rho dv + vd\rho) = \frac{\delta}{\delta t} (p dV)
\end{equation}

Since we are talking about a tiny volume, we can express $3a^2$ as dA. This would result in:
\begin{equation}
(\rho dv + vd\rho)dA = \frac{\delta}{\delta t} (p dV)
\end{equation}

Now I would notice that $(\rho dv + vd\rho) = (\rho v)`$, but this is exactly where the equation suddenly turns out to be wrong. 
I should obtain:
\begin{equation}
(\rho v)dA = \frac{\delta}{\delta t} (p dV)
\end{equation}
from which I can then take the corresponding integrals for the Area and the Volume. But with my method, I arrive to the wrong result of:
\begin{equation}
(\rho v)` dA = \frac{\delta}{\delta t} (p dV)
\end{equation}

What am I doing wrong???

Thanks for your input!

Comment: Can you give the title of the book ?

Comment: Fundamentals of aerodynamics by anderson

Comment: I do notice I did a mistake.. the expression in the right hand should be: $\frac{\delta}{\delta t} (\rho dV)$ so yeah, the dV is missing...

Comment: Why do you treat the velocity as a scalar ? By the way you use the same symbol for the velocity and the volume.

Comment: What difference does it make whether you take velocity as a scalar or not? For this derivation it shouldnt make a difference, should it? Or am I missing out here on something?...

Comment: It is necessary to consider the components: see half top page 2 [here](http://web.mit.edu/16.unified/www/FALL/fluids/Lectures/f06.pdf).

Comment: Yes... I know that expression. But here as well, they just jump directly from a definition to an integral. This is why I wanted to proof this concept by actually going all the way to the details.

Comment: The problem is though, that even with a velocity as a vector, my expression will remain wrong...

Comment: In the x-direction, $\,\dot m_{out}-\dot m_{in}=\frac {\partial (\rho v_x)}{\partial x}dxdydz$ and so the other directions. Then sum and equate to $-\frac {\partial \rho}{\partial t}dxdydz$ . You have the equation in differential form.